# Почему Mysqli Fetch Assoc не присваивается напрямую в While?

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть запрос в бд.

Затем цикл:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
..
}
```

Но почему когда далее я делаю `var_dump($row) - NULL`?  Разве выборка не присваивается  в переменную `row`, и не должен быть вывод последнего значения цикла?

Answer (score 0):

Если после цикла переменная пустая, то  по всей видимости ей передается значение только внутри цикла.

Делайте так - `$result[] = $row;` и получите массив данных.